# Google Chrome pops up "Your preferences can not be read" upon startup

Tags: google-chrome

Had a power outage. After restarting the computer, now whenever I start Google Chrome, a window pops up "Your preferences can not be read. Some features may be unavailable and changes to preferences won't be saved."

Nothing whatsoever in Chrome Help nor in the Chrome Forums as to how to fix the problem.  How can this be resolved?

Additional edit:  Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome does NOT fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue.  Uninstalling Chrome and reinstalling it did not fix the problem, as I would expect; I got the same exact window after the reinstall.

I ran chkdsk once, but that didn't fix the problem either.  However, the second time I ran chkdsk, the problem did go away.  So running chkdsk seems to be the solution, but I have no idea why it took two attempts.

Answer (score 6):

Find your way to the user settings.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Andy\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome
```

Right-click to Properties on "User Data" and go to the *Security/Advanced* tab. Click the box *Replace permission entries…*

Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed by doing the following in Win 7:

- Install Chrome.
- After setup it will display the usual 'your preferences cannot be read'.
- Click OK the these errors.
- After this, Chrome will open a browser window. Go with this window and enter Settings.
- At the users section, click on 'Delete this user', accept all prompts.
- Chrome will display its default page when done.

Close and reopen Chrome, the problem is now gone!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your preferences got corrupted. Try this:

[Create a new browser user profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en)

Backup and rename your `Google\Chrome\User Data` directory. This should set up a new profile for you and fix your issue.

Comment: Good suggestion, but this did not in fact fix the problem. A new "Default" folder got created, but I still get the popup.

Comment: interesting, this is on windows7 i assume? (judging from your question history).. Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling? some of the binaries could have also been corrupted

Comment: This is a Windows XP machine, actually.  I was hoping that this could be fixed without a complete uninstall and reinstall, but if I get no other suggestions that's what I'll try.

Comment: Slightly chrome unrelated, but are you seeing any other issues? did XP ask you to run checkdisk on bootup?

Comment: No unusual problems with anything else other than Chrome.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling does not fix the problem. Same popup after reinstall.  I'll add that to the original question.

Comment: Starting from version "i-don't-remember", single Chrome installation can have multiple user profiles, you can just [add new user](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) to Chrome and then delete the older user.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue by doing the follwing:

- I tried disk check and it did not resolve.
- I then did a disk defragmentation on the drive my chrome is installed on and afterwards it worked like a charm, hope this helps

note: i did not need to reinstall chrome to do this, i just 
closed chrome and started the disk check and disk defrag

Comment: This really should have been a comment for seansand as a follow up step.